# AVMediaTypeVideo capture Still Image Orientation

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I've seen other almost answers to this question but can't seem to get it working. I'm capturing an image from AVMediaTypeVideo and it's orientation is always UIImageOrientation 3 (I don't know what that means in reality).

I've tried to correct it using the status bar orientation but that doesn't seem to have any effect. I don't need to save these images to the camera roll, it's just there now to verify. I'm not sure if that has any effect on the orientation as well.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
let stillImageOutput = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()

var avCaptureVideoPreview : AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?

var error: NSError?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let devices = AVCaptureDevice.devices().filter{ $0.hasMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo) }

    if let captureDevice = devices.first as? AVCaptureDevice  {

        captureSession.addInput(AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice, error: &error))

        captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium

        captureSession.startRunning()

        stillImageOutput.outputSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey:AVVideoCodecJPEG]

        if captureSession.canAddOutput(stillImageOutput) {

            captureSession.addOutput(stillImageOutput)
        }

        avCaptureVideoPreview = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)

        if let previewLayer = avCaptureVideoPreview {

            previewLayer.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, view.bounds.size.width, view.bounds.size.height)

            previewLayer.position = CGPointMake(view.bounds.midX, view.bounds.midY)

            previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill

            let cameraPreview = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, view.bounds.size.width, view.bounds.size.height))

            cameraPreview.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)

            cameraPreview.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:"saveToCamera:"))

            view.addSubview(cameraPreview)
        }
    }

    // Add a selfie button if device is capable

    for device in devices {

        if device.position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.Front {

            // Add selfie button
            println("selfie capable")
        }

    }

}

override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {

    if avCaptureVideoPreview != nil {

        // Orientation

        if (avCaptureVideoPreview!.connection.supportsVideoOrientation == true) {

            avCaptureVideoPreview!.connection.videoOrientation = interfaceOrientationToVideoOrientation(UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarOrientation)
        }

        // Frame 

        avCaptureVideoPreview!.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, view.bounds.size.width, view.bounds.size.height)

        avCaptureVideoPreview!.position = CGPointMake(view.bounds.midX, view.bounds.midY)

        avCaptureVideoPreview!.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill

    }
}

func interfaceOrientationToVideoOrientation(orientation: UIInterfaceOrientation) -> AVCaptureVideoOrientation {

    switch orientation {

    case UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait:
        return AVCaptureVideoOrientation.Portrait
    case UIInterfaceOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown:
        return AVCaptureVideoOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown
    case UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft:
        return AVCaptureVideoOrientation.LandscapeLeft
    case UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeRight:
        return AVCaptureVideoOrientation.LandscapeRight
    default:
        return AVCaptureVideoOrientation.Portrait

    }

}

func saveToCamera(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    if let videoConnection = stillImageOutput.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo) {

        stillImageOutput.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(videoConnection) {

            (imageDataSampleBuffer, error) -> Void in

            var image = UIImage(data: AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(imageDataSampleBuffer))

            // this is not working
            var orientation : UIImageOrientation?

            switch UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarOrientation.rawValue {

            case 1:
                orientation = UIImageOrientation.Up
            case 3:
                orientation = UIImageOrientation.Left
            case 4:
                orientation = UIImageOrientation.Right
            default:
                orientation = UIImageOrientation.Up

            }

            let newImage = UIImage(CGImage: image?.CGImage, scale: 1.0, orientation: orientation!)

            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(newImage, nil, nil, nil)

        }
    }
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
}
```

Comment: you should really tick the great answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit, this does not work for photos captured with the front facing camera, they appear fine in the native photos app but not when shared in Photos on Mac or loaded back from parse.com.

Thanks to @XJones 's answer here [Why does AVCaptureVideoOrientation landscape modes result in upside down still images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7845520/why-does-avcapturevideoorientation-landscape-modes-result-in-upside-down-still-i)

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
let stillImageOutput = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()

var avCaptureVideoPreview : AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?

var error: NSError?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let devices = AVCaptureDevice.devices().filter{ $0.hasMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo) }

    if let captureDevice = devices.first as? AVCaptureDevice  {

        captureSession.addInput(AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice, error: &error))

        captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium

        captureSession.startRunning()

        stillImageOutput.outputSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey:AVVideoCodecJPEG]

        if captureSession.canAddOutput(stillImageOutput) {

            captureSession.addOutput(stillImageOutput)
        }

        avCaptureVideoPreview = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)

        if let previewLayer = avCaptureVideoPreview {

            previewLayer.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, view.bounds.size.width, view.bounds.size.height)

            previewLayer.position = CGPointMake(view.bounds.midX, view.bounds.midY)

            previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill

            let cameraPreview = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, view.bounds.size.width, view.bounds.size.height))

            cameraPreview.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)

            cameraPreview.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:"saveToCamera:"))

            view.addSubview(cameraPreview)
        }
    }

    // Add a selfie button if device is capable

    for device in devices {

        if device.position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.Front {

            // Add selfie button
            println("selfie capable")
        }

    }

}

override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {

    if avCaptureVideoPreview != nil {

        // Orientation

        if (avCaptureVideoPreview!.connection.supportsVideoOrientation == true) {

            var newOrientation : AVCaptureVideoOrientation?

            switch UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation {
            case UIDeviceOrientation.Portrait:
                newOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.Portrait
            case UIDeviceOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown:
                newOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown
            case UIDeviceOrientation.LandscapeLeft:
                newOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.LandscapeRight;
            case UIDeviceOrientation.LandscapeRight:
                newOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.LandscapeLeft
            default:
                newOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.Portrait
            }

            avCaptureVideoPreview!.connection.videoOrientation = newOrientation!

        }

        // Frame 

        avCaptureVideoPreview!.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, view.bounds.size.width, view.bounds.size.height)

        avCaptureVideoPreview!.position = CGPointMake(view.bounds.midX, view.bounds.midY)

        avCaptureVideoPreview!.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill

    }
}

func saveToCamera(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    if let videoConnection = stillImageOutput.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo) {

        stillImageOutput.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(videoConnection) {

            (imageDataSampleBuffer, error) -> Void in

            var image = UIImage(data: AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(imageDataSampleBuffer))

            var imageOrientation : UIImageOrientation?

            switch UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation {

            case UIDeviceOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown:
                imageOrientation = UIImageOrientation.Left
            case UIDeviceOrientation.LandscapeRight:
                imageOrientation = UIImageOrientation.Down
            case UIDeviceOrientation.LandscapeLeft:
                imageOrientation = UIImageOrientation.Up
            case UIDeviceOrientation.Portrait:
                imageOrientation = UIImageOrientation.Right
            default:
                imageOrientation = UIImageOrientation.Right

            }

            var newImage = UIImage(CGImage: image!.CGImage, scale: 1.0, orientation: imageOrientation!)

            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(newImage!, nil, nil, nil)

        }
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
}
```